# Regression Model Proof

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

In the standard regression model where

$$ Y=Xβ+u\ ,$$

with normal errors, under the hypothesis

$$\text{H}_0: Rβ=r$$

where $β$ is $k\times 1$, $R$ a $q\times k$ matrix  with rank $q$: the OLS estimator

$\hat{β} = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y$

satisfies $R\hat{β}-r=0$. In contrast the contained estimator $H_0$ equates the score to zero.

Is this question true, false, or uncertain.

Answer:

I believe its true based on this. Is the below the correct assumptions for this question (sorry about the bad format).

Let $S(b) = (y - Xb)'(y - Xb) - 2\lambda(Rb - r)$.

The constrained estimator $b$ satisfies the first order conditions:
(1) $-X'y + X'Xb - R\lambda = 0$
(2) $Rb - r = 0$

Thus $b = β + (X'X)^{-1}R'\lambda$
 eliminate $\lambda\ $:
$Rb = Rβ + R(X'X)^{-1} R \lambda$
Since $Rb = r$,

$[R((X'X)^{-1}R']r = [R(X'X)^{-1}R']Rβ + \lambda$. Thus, $\lambda = [R(X'X)^{-1}R]^{-1}(r - Rβ)$.
Substitute out $\lambda$:
$b = β + (X'X)^{-1}R'[R(X'X)^{-1}R']^{-1}(r - Rβ)$

Comment: You seem to be inviting comment on your attempted response to a question. This is perfectly acceptable, but your question should probably carry the `self-study` tag. See its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for more information. You already seem to be basically following its recommendations.

Comment: I've attempted to clean up your mathematics - it had some stray characters in it, as if you'd pasted material from a word processor or something. Please check it says what you want.

Comment: So would that be the correct proof? And also how would we get the variance of RB-r to be [R(X'X)^-1R']^-1?

Comment: It looks okay to me, but maybe I missed something.